# How to plot an equation with no analytical solution?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have been trying to plot an equation. The variables are fixed at (for this instance) `a=0.06`, `b=-0.01`, `i=0`, `t=0.005`, `r=0.0025`, `s=0.015` while I intend to vary variable `e`. Some of the functions in the main equations are,

[image: functions]

The equation looks like this,

[image]

I'd ideally like a plot between `Q` and `x` as `e` increases. I replaced variable `e` with w and `N` with U in the code because mathematica said that the original symbols are protected.

```
t = 0.0005
r = 0.00025
A = 0.06
B = -0.01
s = 0.015
i=0
M  =  w*A-i*B
U= t/(1+t*w-t*i)
P= (s/t)*(1+U*(r+t))
Q=M/P
1-Q = (Exp[-1/(x*U)] + Exp[-(r + 2*U)/(x*U*r)])*((1/2)-Q) + Q*Exp[-2*(r+U)/(x*r*U)]
```

I actually don't know how to proceed. My instincts are to find a root of the equation for each value `w` and store the value of x obtained thus. Then find the value of `Q` for that w. Then plot the couplings (Q, x) I get in the end.

I need the plot to be Q vs x for this specific problem (and not w vs x).

Is there a more direct way of plotting x vs Q? If not, could someone please help me out with this as I am fairly new to using Mathematica and I generally work in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

t = 0.0005 // Rationalize;
r = 0.00025 // Rationalize;
A = 0.06 // Rationalize;
B = -0.01 // Rationalize;
s = 0.015 // Rationalize;
i = 0;
M = w*A - i*B;
U = t/(1 + t*w - t*i);
P = (s/t)*(1 + U*(r + t));
```

Note that equations use [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html) ( `==` ) not [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) ( `=` )

```
eqn1 = Q == M/P // Simplify

(* Q == (8 w (2000 + w))/(8000003 + 4000 w) *)

eqn2 = 1 - Q == (Exp[-1/(x*U)] + Exp[-(r + 2*U)/(x*U*r)])*((1/2) - Q) + 
    Q*Exp[-2*(r + U)/(x*r*U)] // Simplify

(* 1 + 1/2 E^(-((2000 + w)/x)) (1 + E^(-8000/x)) (-1 + 2 Q) == 
 Q + E^(-((2 (6000 + w))/x)) Q *)
```

The relation between `Q` and `x` is given by

```
eqnsQx = eqn2 /. Solve[eqn1, w] // Simplify

(* {1 + 1/2 E^((-36000 - 1000 Q + 
     Sqrt[2] Sqrt[8000000 + 4000003 Q + 500000 Q^2])/(
    4 x)) (1 + E^(8000/x)) (-1 + 2 Q) == 
  Q + E^((-20000 - 1000 Q + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[8000000 + 4000003 Q + 500000 Q^2])/(
    2 x)) Q, 
 1 + 1/2 E^(-((
     36000 + 1000 Q + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[8000000 + 4000003 Q + 500000 Q^2])/(
     4 x))) (1 + E^(8000/x)) (-1 + 2 Q) == 
  Q + E^(-((20000 + 1000 Q + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[8000000 + 4000003 Q + 500000 Q^2])/(
     2 x))) Q} *)
```

Use [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) to plot an implicit relationship (equation),

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqnsQx, {Q, -7, 5},
 {x, 15, 16000},
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Q, x}),
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]